# Jface accelerator key not working on macOS when focus is on StyledText widget

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

Within a StyledText or Text widget, a single letter key accelerator is working fine on Windows. However, it is not working on macOS:

- All good on Windows: pressing 'A' when the text view is focused displays the pop-up (and the letter A is not output)
- Fail on macOS: pressing 'A' when the text view is focused does NOT display the pop-up (and the letter A is output)

I'm using the latest version of SWT and Jface packages (provided with Eclipse Oxygen.2). Testing on macOS High Sierra 10.13.

(Note that making the StyledText READ_ONLY at construction does not mitigate the problem; the key still gets processed by the text widget instead of the Jface key binding manager.)

Simple demo snippet below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class AcceleratorsTest {

    static class ActionTest extends Action {
        ActionTest() {
            super("Sample Action");
            setAccelerator('A');
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MessageDialog.openInformation(null, "hello", "hello");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        // menu with one action having the accelerator key 'A'
        MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
        Menu menu = menuManager.createMenuBar((Decorations)shell);
        shell.setMenuBar(menu);
        MenuManager menuFile = new MenuManager("File");
        menuFile.add(new ActionTest());
        menuManager.add(menuFile);
        menuManager.updateAll(true);

        // text widget fills up the main shell
        StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
        text.setText("Accelerators problem inside StyledText:\r\n"
                + " - okay on Windows: pressing A when the text view is focused displays the pop-up (and the letter A is not output)<br>\r\n"
                + " - fail on macOS: pressing A when the text view is focused does NOT display the pop-up (and the letter A is output)");

        // event loop
        shell.open();
        while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if(!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is specific to StyledText - accelerators like this don't seem to work at all on macOS.

Comment: @greg-449 1) they work fine on Table/Tree widgets, for ex. 2) how is it implemented for RCP E4 apps then? (because single-key accelerators work fine there, even on macOS; therefore I would suspect the key handlings facility is not the one used by pure Jface/SWT apps - correct?)

Comment: Well for an e4 RCP you should be using Binding Tables in the e4xmi not the obsolete Action accelerator. But I don't know if that works either for single characters.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks Greg, as said, re:E4, I confirm they do work fine for single chars, on all platforms (of course, defined in the e4xmi model file); anyway... I'm very surprised regarding this issue. is there an open bug for it somewhere on the Eclipse www? Key bindings are crucial, I can't believe I'd be the first one to report this. In the meantime, I started crafting my own key accelerator manager (and that allows me to add missing funcs. in Jface's, such as multiple key accels. per handler, or no tie to Menu items, etc.).

Comment: Just using 'A' as an acceleratpr is extremely unusual, normally it is something like Ctrl+A - accelerators like that work fine.

Comment: They may be unusual but commonplace in _some_ type of applications. I hope you're not suggesting that this would not be a bug, but simply "works as expected" ;-)